# How to show a loading gif image before content loads?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want a simple jquery code that can show a loading gif image before loads any content of a div. It should work with any div id like `#post hentry`, I mean after page loads show loading effect before loads any `div id` content.

This is example content and id:

```
<div id="post hentry">
This is example text content i want to load.
</div>
```

First, `Web-page` will load then show loading gif image before `#post hentry` content loads.

Example script (it’s only sample, it’s not working):

```
$id('#post hentry').block('<img src="images/loadinfo.gif" />');
```

Note : I want to show loading gif image before this HTML Code loads.

```
<div id="post hentry">Images, text, anythings.</div>
```

Another example: I want to load side bar, content frame etc. Look on the stackoverflow.com sidebar or Header banner, jQuery AJAX loading or lazy loading.

Comment: how do you load new content into your div? please share that part of the code as well

Comment: hide div "#post hentry" just before showing the content

Comment: Want to load this: `<div id="post hentry">
This is example text content i want to load.
</div>`

Comment: I want to load `side bar`, `content frame` etc

Comment: While I understand that it may not be easy to ask a question in a foreign language, you can't expect that someone will take the time to give an answer to such a broad and unclear question . Especially looking at your previous questions shows that the chance is high to misunderstand your question.